# Facebook login error in flutter : Bad access token: {"code":190,"message":"Invalid OAuth access token."} ], null)

Tags: android, ios, firebase, flutter, firebase-authentication

I'm trying to achieve Facebook Firebase auth on my flutter application,

I have settled everything up and it goes well, but after Facebook asks for the user's login credentials. it gives me this error :

```
PlatformException(ERROR_INVALID_CREDENTIAL, The supplied auth credential is malformed or has expired. [ Bad access token: {"code":190,"message":"Invalid OAuth access token."} ], null)
```

Here is the code am using :

```dart
  Future faceBookSignIn() async {
    try{
      var result = await _facebookAuth.logIn(['email']);
      print(result.status.toString());
      if (result.status == FacebookLoginStatus.loggedIn){
        final AuthCredential credential = FacebookAuthProvider.getCredential(accessToken: result.accessToken.toString());
        AuthResult facebookResult = await _auth.signInWithCredential(credential);
        FirebaseUser facebookUser = facebookResult.user;
        return _userFromFirebaseUser(facebookUser);
      }
    }catch(e){
      print(e);
    }
  }
```

And here is the packages am using on my `pubspec.yaml`

```yaml
  firebase_auth: ^0.16.0
  google_sign_in: ^4.4.1
  flutter_facebook_login: ^3.0.0
  flutter_auth_buttons: ^0.8.0
```

Comment: Is it working or not? Please have a look at my solution.

Comment: @VinothVino perfectly working, thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Changing the `result.accessToken.toString` to `result.accessToken.token` will solve your problem.

```
FacebookAuthProvider.getCredential(
  accessToken: result.accessToken.token,
),
```