# flutter_facebook_auth: The supplied auth credential is malformed or has expired

Tags: flutter, firebase-authentication, facebook-authentication

I'm trying to use the flutter_facebook_auth 3.3.2+2 package and the firebase_auth 1.0.3 to do the facebook login, I basically copy and paste the code from their doc https://facebook.meedu.app/#/firebase-auth

```
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:flutter_facebook_auth/flutter_facebook_auth.dart';

Future<UserCredential?> signInWithFacebook() async {
  final LoginResult result = await FacebookAuth.instance.login();
  if(result.status == LoginStatus.success){
    // Create a credential from the access token
    final OAuthCredential credential = FacebookAuthProvider.credential(result.accessToken!.token);
    // Once signed in, return the UserCredential
    return await FirebaseAuth.instance.signInWithCredential(credential);
  }
  return null;
}
```

I tried to login with it, but when it goes down to the code `await FirebaseAuth.instance.signInWithCredential(credential);`
It pops the error: `E/flutter (23237): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(186)] Unhandled Exception: [firebase_auth/invalid-credential] The supplied auth credential is malformed or has expired. [ Remote site 5XX from facebook.com for VERIFY_CREDENTIAL ]`

I've checked all the app id, app secret, callback url, package name are matching,
I have no clues what did I do wrong. Please can anybody tell me what is happening?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54922944/fb-login-firebase-auth-error-the-supplied-auth-credential-is-malformed-or-h have you tried this?

Comment: Yeah I've tried everything on there before I post this

Comment: Have you checked API key and secrets?

Comment: Yes I've checked that as well, in the Firebase console, in the xml, in the facebook console. it's all same. Also the package name is matching as well. That's why I'm so confused

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65265093/the-supplied-auth-credential-is-malformed-or-has-expired-flutter-facebook-log ?

Comment: https://github.com/FirebaseExtended/flutterfire/issues/4524#issuecomment-764610739

Comment: This github one works, thank you so much mate!

Comment: I will add answer for future generations!

Comment: Changing the time and timezone of the emulator worked for me [Check this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63682399/11333898)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There could be multiple reasons:
[Choosing wrong app type in Facebook console instead of "Build Connected Experiences"](https://github.com/FirebaseExtended/flutterfire/issues/4524#issuecomment-764610739)

[image]

Also:

- Wrong bundle/app/package id/name
- Bad API key and secrets